# How to populate zend form using data from different database columns?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

I have a form :

```
$houserent = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('houserent');

$houserent      ->setLabel('House Rent :');
$this   ->addElement($houserent);

$tax = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('tax');
$siteName        ->setLabel('Tax :');
$this    ->addElement($tax);

$internet = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('internet');
$internet->setLabel('Internet :');
$this    ->addElement($internet);
```

and my data table "test" is

```
id   name         value
1   house rent    100
2   tax            10
3   internet       10
```

I want to populate the form using the above data from tha database table. But I don't know how to this. Please help me. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can overwrite the populate function in your form.

```
public function populate($data)
{
  foreach($data as $field => $value)
  {
    $this->{$field}->setValue($value);
  }
  return $this;
}
```

where $data is an associated array of name => value.

[edit]

So you form is now:

```
<?php
  class Form_Admin_Settings_Add extends Zend_Form
  {
    public function init()
    {
      $houserent = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('houserent');
      $houserent->setLabel('House Rent :');
      $this->addElement($houserent);

      $tax = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('tax');
      $siteName->setLabel('Tax :');
      $this->addElement($tax);

      $internet = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('internet');
      $internet->setLabel('Internet :');
      $this->addElement($internet);
    }

    public function populate($data)
    {
      foreach($data as $field => $value)
      {
        $this->{$field}->setValue($value);
      }
      return $this;
    }
  }
```

In your controller:

```
<?php
  //instantiate form and model
  $form = new Form_Admin_Settings_Add();
  $model = new Model_Test();

  //get results
  $results = $model->fetchAll()->toArray();
  $data = array();

  //put results into our data array as name => value
  foreach($results as $r)
  {
    $data[$r['name']] = $r['value'];
  }

  //populate our form
  $form->populate(data);
  echo $form;
```

Comment: If I add your code in my form class I gives the following errors. As I'm novice in zend can you describe it little bit detail.

Strict Standards: Declaration of Form_Admin_Settings_Add::populate() should be compatible with that of Zend_Form::populate() in /opt/lampp/htdocs/BusinessForum/application/forms/Admin/Settings/Add.php on line 3

Fatal error: Call to a member function setValue() on a non-object in /opt/lampp/htdocs/BusinessForum/application/forms/Admin/Settings/Add.php on line 49

Comment: The first error suggests that the function declaration is different to that in Zend_Form. Looking at Zend Framework 1.11, the functions look the same (`public function populate($data)`). What version of Zend Framework are you using? The second error message is that the form element did not exist in the form, which I may have resolved in the updated answer?

Comment: Parnaby -King , can please tell me is it possible to write populate function inside controller instead of form class.

Thanks

Comment: Looking at my supplied answer, you do not need to write the populate function in the form as it is all being done in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Try some like this:

```
class Form extends Zend_Form {

   public funcition Form(){
      $houserent = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('houserent');
      $houserent->setLabel('House Rent :')
                ->setValue($this->_Data['houserent']);
      $this->addElement($houserent);
   }

   public function setData($Data){
        $this->_Data = $Data;
        return $this;
    }
}
```